Delivery Plan in Azure DevOps
I am managing projects having multiple Hives. Each Hive has 10 squads and the project cut across multiple squads.
I have created delivery plan to track project in ADO.
I would like to get inputs on the below use case if this is possible to achieve

a) Delivery plan to list status with the hierarchy of Feature > Story across squads. Note the squads have iteration field defined with Sprint #. Currently these are getting listed in the delivery plan. However, I am unable to get the Feature being listed since they get delivered across sprints and the iteration is not defined with sprint name

b) How to get the rolledup view of capacity available vs delivery planned in story points in each sprint in the delivery plan

c) For the past sprints that are completed how to get the squad velocity

d) Is this Delivery Plan the right tool to track the project delivery like a project plan (mpp)or any other better way to track a project end to end


e) is there a threshold set and alert sent for teams who don't have sufficient backlogs in future sprint
Looking forward an expert suggestion to implement better practice

For your questions:

Delivery plan to list status with the hierarchy of Feature > Story across squads. Note the squads have iteration field defined with Sprint #. Currently these are getting listed in the delivery plan. However, I am unable to get the Feature being listed since they get delivered across sprints and the iteration is not defined with sprint name
If a sprint (iteration) contains dates that overlap with another one, the work items assigned with this sprint will could not be able to show on Delivery Plan. You should avoid sprints contain overlapping dates when defining them.

How to get the rolledup view of capacity available vs delivery planned in story points in each sprint in the delivery plan
Delivery Plan does not provide any Analytics view chart. You can go "Sprints" > "Analytics" to try to get the view charts for each team in each sprint.

For the past sprints that are completed how to get the squad velocity
It is not possible to get squad velocity from Delivery Plan. As mentioned above, try to get the information from "Sprints" > "Analytics".

Is this Delivery Plan the right tool to track the project delivery like a project plan (mpp)or any other better way to track a project end to end
You should use Delivery Plan together with other features of Azure Boards (such as Analytics views, Queries, etc..) to track/monitor the information you require. Delivery Plan cannot completely replace other features to do everything.



EDIT:
Delivery Plan can display all the Backlog level work item types (Epics, Features and Stories, and Bugs if you set they are managed with requirements.)
you can open the Settings window of a plan to set which projects, which teams and which types of Backlog works will display on that plan.

To report consolidated sprint of squads across hive, you can do like as below:

Create a project dashboard. See "Add, rename, and delete dashboards in Azure DevOps".

Configure the burndown or burnup widgets on the dashboard. The two widgets give you flexibility to create charts for any type of scope or number of teams within specified time periods. Burndown charts focus on remaining work, while burnup charts focus on completed work. See "Configure a burndown or burnup widget".




Thanks for your response 1. The delivery plan is only showing storys and bugs. The stories are linked to features, however they don't get listed in the sprints. How do I get the track of features which will get delivered in several sprints in delivery plan. Currently features have dependencies . Hence both are not getting displayed in delivery plan


As a project manager I would like to report consolidated sprint  of squads across hive. If delivery plan can't give this, what's the way out, instead of going into individual teams sprint analytics


@Suresh, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT). Check and try with it.

Thanks for your response. For displaying the progress with hierarchical view of Features > Epics > Stories in the delivery plan how do we go about. understand the settings we can choose the team and either feature or epic or story, based on this delivery plan list the work item

@Suresh, On a delivery plan, each type of work items for each team are grouped in a swimlane. And each work item shows as a card in the swimlane. You cannot set the hierarchical view of Features > Epics > Stories, and you see this type of hierarchical view on the Boards > Backlogs page of each team.
